# How to allow Googlebot and Bingbot to crawl mysite?

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, robots.txt, googlebot, bingbot

Recently I got email message from Google that `Googlebot` `cant access your site`. I tried to look for some articles on the internet about this issue and most them points its because of *robots.txt* file being set as  `User-agent: * Disallow: /` so does was mine.

How can I allow `Goolebot` and `Bingbot` to crawl the content of my site? I am going to put as below but I am not sure. Am I in the right track?

```
User-agent: googlebot
User-agent: google
User-agent: bingbot
User-agent: bing

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: You are looking at this backwards. Normally, you allow all and block specific bots. It is not possible to use the robots.txt to block rogue scraper bots. Only valid bots will read the robots.txt file. This means that you can only block those who follow the rules and behave well. If you simply empty out your robots.txt file and block unwanted bots as you find them, you will be fine. This is how it is normally done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the last two lines of your robots.txt file take precedence over the first four as the syntax of those first four lines is incorrect. As a result Google is blocked from viewing your website.

To allow Google and Bing you must specifically and individually allow each crawler:

```
User-agent: googlebot
Disallow: 

User-agent: bingbot
Disallow: 

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Going forward, to find out if your robots.txt file will allow Google to index your site test it inside of your [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) account. Also see the [official robots.txt documentation](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

Comment: John, What makes a differnce what if i leave it as `User-agent: *
Disallow: /`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Ok what is the differece between `User-agent: googlebot
Disallow: 

User-agent: bingbot
Disallow: 

User-agent: *
Disallow: /` the one on your solution and just `User-agent: *
Disallow: /` is there any difference between the two? the third one allows all bots including google and  bing

Comment: The first two lines allow googlebot to crawl your site. Same for bingbot on the next two. The last lines excludes all others who aren't those two bots.

Comment: ok so the last line blocks all robots  while the first two line allow google and bing to crawl my site respectively is that right? so googlebot and bingbot will see my site

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1):

Based on the contents of your robots.txt file and your needs, you're better off making that file entirely empty or even better, maybe with a link to the sitemap files so search engines can find your URLs.

I suggest this because crawlers normally think they are allowed to access anything. By specifically using `Disallow`, you're trying to tell at least one crawler that they are *not allowed* to access something on your site.

Here's a link to an example of a robots.txt that google uses:

http://www.google.ca/robots.txt